# Why does this code not produce a square 2d-array? What makes it become triangular?

Tags: python, arrays, dimensional

I'm trying to print a square two-dimensional array of 0s. I don't understand why I keep getting a triangular shape with this code. Why is it that with each ROW I print, I print one less column?

```
def ar(i):
    j = i
    for i in range(i):
        for j in range(j):
            print('0', end=" ")
        print()
```

Comment: Because you overwrite your own `j` ?    `for ` **`j`** `in range(` **`j`** `):`

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`range(5)` will produce the values from 0 to 4 - one less then the inputted number.

```
i = 5
j = i   # this is overwritten by the loop-j
for _ in range(i):       # on the first i
    for j in range(j):       # j will get 4 at max, so for the next i your j 
        print('0', end=" ")  # only produce a range(4), then (3) ... hence: triangular
    print()
```

Your inner loop `j` overwrites your local `j` and due to the nature of `range()` it will decrease by 1 for each outer loop.

Fix:

You do not need named loop-vars, substitute with `_`:

```
def ar(i):
    for _ in range(i):
        for _ in range(i): # no j needed at all
            print('0', end=" ")
        print()

ar(5)
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```